# Querying all values in eloquent where clause

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I was trying to write an eloquent query that fetches results based on the date. But the date will be given separately as year, month and day. I wanted the query to work when I also pass 'all' for one or more of the inputs (like for all days in a month if the day is given as 'all'). I know I can do it using different 'if' combinations, but I wanted to have some easy way to do it. Is there any way?

Here is the code I have written.

```
$year = $request->input('year');
$month = $request->input('month');
$day = $request->input('day');
$reports = DailyReport::whereYear('date', $year)
           ->whereMonth('date', $month)
           ->whereDay('date', $day)->get();
```

Comment: no I think some sort of conditional is necessary e.g. using [`when`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#conditional-clauses)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked finally, after looking all the helpful answers of course.

```
$year = $request->input('year');
$month = $request->input('month');
$day = $request->input('day');
$reports = DailyReport::when($year!='all', function ($query) use($year) {
               return $query->whereYear('date', $year);
           })
           ->when($month!='all', function ($query) use($month) {
               return $query->whereMonth('date', $month);
           })
           ->when($day!='all', function ($query) use($day) {
               return $query->whereDay('date', $day);
           })->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it out this

```php
$reports = DailyReport::when($request->has('year'), function ($query) use ($request) {
    $query->whereYear('date', $request->year);
})
    ->when($request->has('month'), function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->whereMonth('date', $request->month);
    })
    ->when($request->has('day'), function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->whereDay('date', $request->day);
    })->get();
```

[laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#conditional-clauses)